# VS Code Error - Won't compile my contract

Tags: solidity, version-pragma

VS code does not seem to recognise my pragma line in the contract and keeps throwing an error suggesting I use a the v 0.8.17 but this is written in my contract as per the image? Also, I have checked the truffle-config.js file and the correct pragma version is specified the same as in the contract - 0.8.17

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much information, your file seems fine, try:

- Saving the file, making sure everything's up to date.
- Run `truffle compile --reset`